# Given a space, what is the inner product?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

I am always confused about what norm or inner product should I use given a specific space.
When talking about continuously differentiable functions, we mean $C^1$ not $L_{2}$ functions right? 
Then can I use the norm $<f,g>=\int f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$ which I think refers to the $L_{2}$ only (is it?) here? And if I can, is it because all norms (so inner product) are equivalent?
I have this question because I was trying to use the theorem:
An orthonormal sequence is complete iff $\sum|<x,e_{k}>|^2=||x||^2$.
And if the orthonormal sequence is complete, we then have $<x,y>=\sum <x,e_{k}>\overline{<y,e_{k}>}$.
And I already known that $e_{k}$ is complete in $H=L_{2}$, but the reason I'm hesitating is that the functions are 'continuously differentiable fucntions', which I think should be $C^1$ but not $L_{2}$.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Your inner product seems to work only for continuous(ly differenetiable) functions **with compact support**

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the continuously differentiable functions are on closed interval [-pi,pi] and are periodic, but I think this still cannot guarantee compact support right? So which means I cannot use this inner product here? But then what is the common inner product we are referring to on continuously differentiable functions on closed interval?

Comment: @J.Y It depends on context. The two most common that come to mind are the $L^2$ inner product and the Sobolev $H^1$ (aka $W^{1,2}$) inner product. There is no inner product that induces the $C^1$ norm that I reference in my answer.

Comment: @J.Y: Are you studying Fourier series? If this is the context, then the inner product which you work with is probably the $L^2$ inner product over $[-\pi,\pi]$ (that is, $\left< f, g \right> := \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \overline{g(x)} \, dx$). Just take note that $C^1_{\text{periodic}}([-\pi,\pi])$ together with $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ is not a Hilbert space because it is not complete.

Comment: @levap Thanks for your help! Yes, when studying orthonormal sequence in functional analysis. And when given a space, it seems that we just pick certain inner products. But I remember that when talking about inner product and norm, we usually use the sup norm for C space, and it seems widely true that norm=sqrt(inner product) in our problems, but it makes more sense to use L2 inner product on the problem I'm working on, so I got confused LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not* all norms are equivalent in infinite dimensional spaces. This means that, for example, $C^1(D)$ with the "$C^1(D)$ norm", i.e. $\| f \|_{C^1(D)} = \sup_{x \in D} |f(x)| + \sup_{x \in D} |f'(x)|$, is different from $C^1(D)$ with the $L^2$ norm. For one thing, the former is complete (as a metric space) while the latter is not. This means that in infinite dimensions, even if all you care about is topology, you *must* say something about the norm that you are using in order to properly make sense of your statements.

One important fact is that $C^1$ embeds into $L^2$ if the domain is bounded. Thus if you have a complete orthonormal sequence on a bounded domain, then it is also "complete for $C^1$", i.e. you can expand any $C^1$ function in terms of the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So whether an orthonormal sequence is complete or not has nothing to do with the inner product or norm I choose right? Only the space matters?

Comment: @J.Y No, it does matter, because the convergence of the expansion is in the norm induced by the inner product.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, what do you mean by 'C1 embeds into L2', is it 'C1 is a subset of L2'? but I guess you don't mean this..

Comment: @J.Y "Embeds into" usually means "is a subset of and the inclusion map is nice". In this case the inclusion map is continuous.

Comment: Thanks you, and referring to your last comment, can I say that since orthonormal sequence is complete in $L_{2}$, and $C^{1}\subset L_{2}$, so as long as I'm using the same inner product for both spaces, and the domain is bounded, that orthonormal sequence is also complete in $C^{1}$?

Comment: @J.Y Sure, that holds.

Answer (score 2):

The inner product/norm on a specific vector space should be defined explicitly or, as is more often the case, understood implicitly from the context. For example, consider the space

$$ C^1([a,b]) := \{ f \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \, | \, f \text{ is continuously differentiable} \}. $$

Without any context, this is just a vector space. Two possible structures you can put on it are:

1. The $L^2$-inner product defined by
   $$ \left< f, g \right>_{L^2} := \int_a^b f(x) \overline{g(x)} \, dx. $$
   Using this inner product, we have a notion of norm $\| f \|_{L^2} := \sqrt{\left< f, f \right>_{L^2}}$. Now, $C^1([a,b])$ together with $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_{L^2}$ is an inner produt space but it is not complete so it is not a Hilbert space.
2. The $C^1$ norm is defined by
   $$ \| f \|_{C^1} := \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)| + \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x)|. $$
   The space $C^1([a,b])$ together with $\| \cdot \|_{C^1}$ is a complete normed space (a Banach space) but it is not a Hilbert space (we haven't defined an inner product and in fact, it is not possible to define an inner product whose associated norm is $\| f \|_{C^1}$).

Which structure you care about and use depends on the context. In many (but not all) cases one wants to work with a complete vector spaces so it often makes more sense to consider $(C^1([a,b]), \| \cdot \|_{C^1})$ than ($C^1([a,b]), \left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_{L^2})$.